# How to remove index.html from home URL?

Tags: html

I have a 5 pages static website. On the logo, I have the link for homepage `index.html`. When I click on the logo it redirects me to homepage and changes the URL in address bar to `www.mydomain.com/index.html`.

For some SEO purpose, I want this url to remain as `www.mydomain.com/` without the `index.html` at the end of the URL.

How can I achieve this? Does this require any rule in `.htaccess` or any other solution?

Comment: Change `index.html` to `/`

Comment: instead of href="index.html", do this href="/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the link to point to `/` instead of `/index.html`. Apache will route any request made to `/` to a fitting index file.

Answer (score 2):

/* in place of index.html use "/" then it will go to home page /*

```
 <!-- instead of this -->
 <a href="index.html">home</a>
 <!-- use like this -->
 <a href="/">home</a>
```